# "Copy" an arc in Neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I want to MATCH structures like

```
(a) -[r]-> (b) -[:SPECIAL_LABEL]-> (c)
```

and then CREATE or MERGE a relation

```
(a)-[s]->(c)
```

where `s` has the very same labels as `r` (so it is a "copy" of r, pointing to `(c)` instead of `(b)`.

Can I achieve this with a cypher query? Or should I write a Java program that gives a list of arcs to the database (through the transactional http endpoint)?

I am using Neo4j 2.3.7.

Comment: How many different labels have nodes?

Comment: You mean: How many different labels are used on the arcs? That would be about 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [cannot create dynamic labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28648891/syntax-error-on-running-cypher-query-with-dynamic-node-label) with plain Cypher. APOC provides [such a procedure](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_creating_data), but APOC only works on 3.x+. With Neo4j 2.3.7, your best option is to implement this feature in Java.

Answer (score 1):

If the labels are known and they are not so much it is possible to use a construction ["pseudo-if"](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/08/22/neo4j-load-csv-handling-empty-columns/):

```
match (a) -[r]-> (b) -[:SPECIAL_LABEL]-> (c)
with a, c, type(r) as relType
FOREACH(if IN CASE WHEN relType='type1' THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
  MERGE (a)-[r:type1]->(b)
)
FOREACH(if IN CASE WHEN relType='type2' THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
  MERGE (a)-[r:type2]->(b)
)
FOREACH(if IN CASE WHEN relType='type3' THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
  MERGE (a)-[r:type3]->(b)
)
RETURN (a)-->(b)
```

P.S. There is no relationship `label`. But they have a `type`. Only one.

Comment: Actually, I don't understand what your queries are doing ... why do we need a random number?

Comment: In this case it is necessary only for an example. As on the basis of known values to create a relationship with the desired label.

Comment: I guess that you are right: If you have a known list of 10 labels, you can probably construct 10 queries that achieve what you want to achieve. I will think about that. But please either erase, explain or change your example because it does not really fit the question.